# What does the “Only my files” option in Windows 8.1 setup migrate?

Tags: windows-8.1, setup

Does it migrate the entire profile, including AppData and the registry?

Comment: It will only move your personal documents.  AppData isn't included.

Answer (score 1):

No, **Keep personal files only** Upgrade Path keeps only data i.e., data in the User (s) folder (Contacts, Desktop, Downloads, Favorites, Links, My Documents, My Music, My Pictures, My Videos, Saved Games, Searches) or Libraries (Documents, Music, Pictures, Videos).

In other words, **Keep personal files only** Upgrade Path is a trimmed down or limited version of the Migration.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? As far as I know it's accurate.